# Move menu next to logo instead of below or above in WordPress theme (header.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to move the menu next to the logo instead of under it in an WordPress theme.
See the actual page I'm working on here: http://wwconsult.no/client/alive/

I found the code for the menus placement in the header.php, here's the snippet:

```
<?php
if ( $smof_data['head_menu_style'] == "menu_default" ){

    if ( has_nav_menu('top_navigation', 'GoGetThemes') ) {
        echo '<div id="menu_back">';
            menu_back();
        echo '</div>';
    }
      echo'<div class="container">'.$logo.'
                    <div class="nav'.$navClass.'">
                        <nav>
                            '.$parallax_menu.'
                        </nav>
                    </div>';
                    if(!is_page_template('home-index.php')){
                        echo '<div class="mob_nav"><nav><span class="trigger"></span>'.$parallax_menu.'</nav></div>';
                    } else{
                        echo '<div class="mob_nav js"><nav><span class="trigger"></span>'.$parallax_menu.'</nav></div>';
                    }
        echo        '</div>';

}   else if ( $smof_data['head_menu_style'] == "menu_dropdown" ) {

    echo'<div class="container">'.$logo.'
                <div class="nav'.$navClass.'">
                    <nav>
                        <div id="menu_current" class="'.$menu_cur.'">
                            <a href="'.$href.'" class="menu_1">
                                <span class="menu_name">'.$smof_data["home_menu_name"].'</span><span class="hover"><span class="arr"></span></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        '.$parallax_menu.'
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="mob_nav js"><nav><span class="trigger"></span>'.$parallax_menu.'</nav></div>
            </div>';

    if ( has_nav_menu('top_navigation', 'GoGetThemes') ) {
        echo '<div id="menu_back">';
            menu_back();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    // Header Border
    echo'<div class="head_box bot_box"></div>';
}
?>
```

I'm no php wizard, but I have tried to make it work without much succsses. Got it above the logo, got blank page, but that about it... Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace below line

```
echo'<div class="container">'.$logo.'
            <div class="nav'.$navClass.'">
```

with

```
 echo'<div class="container">'.$logo;
if ( has_nav_menu('top_navigation', 'GoGetThemes') ) {
    echo '<div id="menu_back">';
        menu_back();
    echo '</div>';
}
echo '<div class="nav'.$navClass.'">
```

Comment: revert back yourcode then i have update code above. pl try that